# Asynchronous function returns async metadata (including result) instead of just result

Tags: c#, json, asynchronous, .net-core, async-await

I'm writing an API with .NET Core 3.1. This API has an asynchronous function called `GetSomeProperty()`, which I use in an endpoint (called `Get`).

When receiving the response from this endpoint, the `results` properties are "moved down" one layer, and wrapped in metadata from the asynchronous method, like this:

```
"results": [
    {
        "result": {//actual result here}
        "id": 1,
        "status": 5,
        "isCanceled": false,
        "isCompleted": true,
        "creationOptions": 0,
        "isFaulted": false
    },
    {
        "result": {//actual result here}
        "id": 2,
        "status": 5,
        "isCanceled": false,
        "isCompleted": true,
        "creationOptions": 0,
        "isFaulted": false
    }
]
```

I don't want these results to be wrapped in this "asynchronous" wrapper.

While keeping the method asynchronous, how can I return the task result, instead of an object containing the task result?

There are two reasons why I haven't used `.Result`:

1. Using `.Result` is considered bad practice, as it can cause locks if the task hasn't yet completed.
2. I couldn't figure out where to put it. It doesn't seem to fit anywhere, as far as I can tell.

Here is the code (*please bear in mind this has been significantly diluted and simplified for example purposes*):

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<object> Get(string someParameter)
{   
    //Do stuff

    var things = BuildACollectionOfItems();
    var results = things.Select(x => x.IrrelevantThing).OrderBy(x => x.SomethingIrrelevant).Select(async x =>
    {
        return new
        {
            x.Id,
            SomeProperty = await GetSomeProperty(x.Id)
        };
    }).ToArray();

    return new
    {
        Results = ((IEnumerable<object>) results),
        SomeIrrelevantThing = someIrrelevantThing
    };
}

private async Task<bool> GetSomeProperty(int id)
{
    var somethingFromAServer = (await _thingProvider.GetThing()).TheProperty;

    //Do stuff here

    var thing = _context.Stuff.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Thing == somethingFromAServer);

    //Do some more stuff

    return thing.Stuff;
}
```

Comment: A side note: consider a suffix `Async` for your `async` methods: `async Task<bool> GetSomePropertyAsync(int id)`.

Comment: Partly a guess, but is `things.Select()` awaitable?  For example: `var results = await things.Select(...)`  Structurally it just appears that `Get()` isn't itself awaiting anything, and results is getting a list of tasks.

Comment: Somewhere you're failing to unwrap a task - usually a missing `await`. Good places to check are places where you've forced the variable to be `object` - which can reference anything, including a `Task<object>` - and check what actual types have been inferred for your `var` variables.

Comment: @dymanoid good point, I'll keep that in mind from now on.

Comment: @David, I just checked, it isn't awaitable apparently. Do you know what I can do to make it awaitable? (btw, I'm very new to async programming, this is my first project with it lol, so sorry about misunderstanding)

Comment: Also, if it's any use... `things.Select(async x)` isn't the only LINQ method used... it's actually more like this: `things.Select(x).OrderBy.Select(async x)`

Comment: @Jessica: Is `.Select()` in this case the standard LINQ method on an `IEnumerable`?  If so then this looks very promising: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14938467/calling-async-method-in-ienumerable-select  Perhaps an extra couple steps, but the idea is to await all of the tasks within the results before returning the whole thing.  I have no way to test it right now, but it *might* be as simple as changing your assignment at the end of that method to `Results = Task.WhenAll(results)`

Comment: @David It is the standard LINQ method on `IEnumerable<>`, yes. I'll look at that post now, thanks!

Comment: @David you're a star, that works, thanks :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `Select` returns `IEnumerable<Task>` (because it is passed an `async` function); you can use `Task.WhenAll` to wait for them all to complete, and unwrap the results:

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<object> Get(string someParameter)
{   
    //Do stuff

    var things = BuildACollectionOfItems();
    var results = await Task.WhenAll(things
        .Select(x => x.IrrelevantThing)
        .OrderBy(x => x.SomethingIrrelevant)
        .Select(async x => new
        {
            x.Id,
            SomeProperty = await GetSomeProperty(x.Id)
        }));

    return new
    {
        Results = ((IEnumerable<object>) results),
        SomeIrrelevantThing = someIrrelevantThing
    };
}
```